# Laravel regex validation strange behavior

Tags: regex, validation, laravel-4, preg-match

When i am using `preg_match` to validate a `input` it behaves as i want.

```
$str = "abc-'xx";
$is_valid = preg_match("/[^A-Za-z'-]/", $str); // output => true
```

But when I am using laravel validation

```
$rules = [
    'name' => "regex:/[^A-Za-z'-]/"
];
```

**OR**

```
$rules = [
    'name' => ["regex:/[^A-Za-z'-]/"]
];
```

it always failed.

Why? and How can i solve this?

Comment: Add anchors `^` and `$` and `+`, try `/^[^A-Za-z'-]+$/`

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: Try `$rules = array(
    'name' => array("regex:/^[^A-Za-z'-]*$/")
);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using regex `/^[A-Za-z\-\']+$/`

```
$rules = [
    'name' => ["regex:/^[A-Za-z\-\']+$/"]
];
```

But couldn't find a reason, Appreciate someone can explain this.

Comment: Is `addslashes` enabled in the php.ini? If not, try enabling and using `'name' => ["regex:/^[A-Za-z'-]+$/"]`.